# Why does Notepad++ display question marks for a language other than English?

Tags: html, notepad++, right-to-left

[image: 1]

The circle in red is where I put my rtl arabic language. I wanted to use it as an example on my web page that used RTL layout. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure your editor's font supports the characters you're trying to use? It looks to me like the font simply can't render whatever you're typing

Comment: Would suggest switching from `notepad++` to `visual studio code` if you are learning programming for frontend development, unless your teacher specifically said to use `notepad++` for some weird reason. It will make life a lot easier and it also supports lost of fonts. Not sure if it supports your language but it does support a lot. So its just a TIP for the future.

Comment: Encoding -> UTF-8?

Comment: @SuperStormer wow i didn't even notice that, kudo for the help btw.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on my comment:

The question marks indicate that characters that can't be decoded by the current encoding. In the bottom right corner, you can see that the current encoding is "ANSI".

You need to change the encoding to UTF-8, as that is (most likely) the correct encoding for the file. Do so via Encoding -> UTF-8 in the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly an `Encoding` problem. When an editor doesn't recognize an encoding, it often display question marks `?` instead of the characters it doesn't understand.

What you can do (besides getting a better editor) is to open the file in `Windows Notepad`. It actually supports several encodings. You can choose encoding in the open dialog. Try different encodings, and if you succeed (the text is shown correctly), then use '`Save as'` and choose '`Utf-8`' as encoding. That should work in Notepad++.